# How to prove $T'$ is finer than $T$

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $d$ and $d'$ be two metrics on the set $X$ and  $T$
, $T'$ are induced by $d $and $d'$ respectively.

Assumption: here is a positive number $k$ such that $k\operatorname{d(x, y)} \leq\operatorname{d'(x, y)}$ for every pair of points $x$ and $y$ in $X$.

Q: Prove that $T'$ is finer than $T$.

I made a step making a claim : $B_d'(x,δ) ⊆ B_d(x,ε)$   but couldn't advance anymore from here..
Any explanations?

Answer (score 0):

You need to show that every open subset in $T$ is also open in $T'$. So take $U\in T$. By the definition for any $x\in U$ there is $\epsilon>0$ such that $B_d(x,\epsilon)\subseteq U$. Bu you've already shown that $B_{d'}(x,\delta)\subseteq B_d(x,\epsilon)$ for some $\delta>0$. And thus every point in $U$ belongs to $U$ together with some $d'$-ball around it. Thus $U$ is open in $T'$.

Comment: sorry but what I meant claim was that I set it as a goal of the proof and I couldn't make it yet